# Cyrillic URLs in Google Chrome?

Tags: javascript, url, url-encoding

I'm having troubles with cyrillic URLs in my site. Well, I change my URLs with Javascript (jQuery) and cyrillic characters work fine in every browser instead Google Chrome, where it's shown thir unicodes. I thought that the URLs wasnt decoded, so I tried one Javascript function to decode them to a normal format but nothing has changed. So any ideas how to solve this problem?

My URL is something like that:

```
http://site.com/index.html#начало
```

But in GC is shown like that:

```
http://site.com/index.html#%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%BE
```

Any help?

Comment: It's just encoded. If you copy this url (from GC) to any other browser's address bar it still works fine. Lok at this for example http://www.blooberry.com/indexdot/html/topics/urlencoding.htm

Comment: Well, yeah I saw that and I read about all those characters that are not printable, but there are sites I have seen which use cyrillic characters. For example this one: http://mallgabrovo.bg/магазини-и-услуги.html

Comment: GC download in progress... In FF it's normal (even FF shows url as encoded in 'view source'). I think this is a way how GC shows URLs with non-english characters , but I'll try it in GC soon.

Comment: yes, now I see in GC that this bulgarian website has non-encoded URLs. What server-side language you use? PHP?

Comment: Btw, could you post small piece of document's source (HTML) where you have links with Cyrillic characters in it (e.g. HTML <a> tag)?

Answer (score 0):

It is not only Chrome, if you would paste your URl directly (or as a bookmark..) into IE8 it can also cause problems.

An URL (by specification) cannot contain cyrillics. We used to have them but got rid off them, too many issues.

see also: 
[URL with Cyrrilic querystring not working in IE (but working in Firefox)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4368032/532498)

Comment: I see... Maybe I will have to do without cyrillic in my URLs, because of all these troubles around it, even if I really wanted to have it.

Comment: In original form it can't (by spec). But every character may be part of url if it is properly encoded (e.g. arabic, chinese, greek, japanese, etc). Some browsers automatically rewrite url encoded query to its original form (most of new generation browsers), even you put it (in address bar) in form of "percent encoded string". Sometimes, there's nothing we can do to fix some issues caused by specific browser.

Comment: @ Wh1T3h4Ck5: I know. You try to give an answer to the question I linked to, and we will discuss futher. I know from experience it gives a lot of problems..

Answer (score 0):

Try using functions like [rawurlencode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.rawurlencode.php) and [rawurldecode()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.rawurldecode.php).

**Example:**

```
   $url = "http://site.com/index.html";
   $url_suffix = "#начало";

   $url_enc = $url . rawurlencode($url_suffix);
   echo "$url_enc<br />";

   $url_dec = rawurldecode($url_enc);
   echo "$url_dec<br />";
```

**Output** (In browser):

```
http://site.com/index.html%23%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%BE
http://site.com/index.html#начало
```

rawurlencode() and rawurldecode() are safe if you try send parameter like email address using GETs (urlencode() and urldecode() are not).

Also set your page **meta** like this

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```

Answer (score 0):

In Chrome, what works for me is use decodeURIComponent (native function) when getting the url. Something like this:

decodeURIComponent(window.location.href)

Going to an encoded url will just work then.

Answer (score 0):

Google Chrome always encode his urls, but it does not let it slip.
Try this out: 
[COPY URL extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/copy-url/mkhnbhdofgaendegcgbmndipmijhbili?hl=ru)
You can open source code and see how it works.